# BitBucket pipeline fails on test cases

Tags: php, cakephp, deployment, bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

I'm having hard time to configure a BitBucket pipeline to deploy a CakePHP application to a hosting server. 
Reading some tutorials I've ended up with this pipeline:

```
image: edbizarro/bitbucket-pipelines-php7

pipelines:
  branches:
    master:
      - step:
          caches:
            - composer
          script:
            - composer install --no-interaction --no-progress --prefer-dist
            - composer test
            - composer deploy-to-production
```

but it always fails:

- Build setup -> OK
- composer install -> OK
- composer test -> FAIL

> +composer test
>   phpunit --colors=always
>   Deprecated Error: Plugin::load() is deprecated. Use Application::addPlugin() instead. This method will be removed in 4.0.0. - /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/config/bootstrap.php, line: 179
>    You can disable deprecation warnings by setting `Error.errorLevel` to `E_ALL & ~E_USER_DEPRECATED` in your config/app.php. in [/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Core/functions.php, line 311]
>
> PHPUnit 6.5.14 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.
>
> Exception: Unable to insert fixtures for "App\Test\TestCase\Controller\CustomersControllerTest" test case. SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory in [/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/TestSuite/Fixture/FixtureManager.php, line 380]
>   Script phpunit --colors=always handling the test event returned with error code 244

I cannot `ls` the virtual remote folders but I can mine... so I inspected `App\Test\TestCase\Controller\CustomersControllerTest`:

```
<?php
namespace App\Test\TestCase\Controller;

use App\Controller\CustomersController;
use Cake\TestSuite\IntegrationTestTrait;
use Cake\TestSuite\TestCase;

class CustomersControllerTest extends TestCase
{
    use IntegrationTestTrait;

    public $fixtures = [
        'app.Customers',
        'app.Orders'
    ];

    public function testIndex()
    {
        $this->markTestIncomplete('Not implemented yet.');
    }

    public function testView()
    {
        $this->markTestIncomplete('Not implemented yet.');
    }

    public function testAdd()
    {
        $this->markTestIncomplete('Not implemented yet.');
    }

    public function testEdit()
    {
        $this->markTestIncomplete('Not implemented yet.');
    }

    public function testDelete()
    {
        $this->markTestIncomplete('Not implemented yet.');
    }
}
```

Because I'm not using tests, can I (safely) avoid the `composer test` step?

By the way, on the hosting server the PHP version is 5.6 while in the pipeline's image is specified version 7. Might this lead to a problem?

Comment: If you not use test then remove ```- composer test```; **Deprecated Error: Plugin::load()** load your plugins from src/Application.php. **PHP version is 5.6** test local your app with same php version

Comment: Ok, but it seems it does not exist such a "edbizarro/bitbucket-pipelines-php5.6"...